# Api error: Request header field Cache-Control is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: php, ajax, api

I am trying to fetch data from an API. I tested it using postman, it give me perfect response. When I copy the code from postman and paste it in my test file i am getting this error

> Request header field Cache-Control is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Below is the code I am using.

```
    <? php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Cache-Control,x-secret-key');
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>TestApi</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){   
var settings = {
  "async": true,
"crossDomain": true,
  "url": "",
  "method" : "GET",
  "headers": {
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
 }
}
$.ajax(settings).done(function(data){
    console.log(data.result);
});
```

What may be the reason for this, also I am getting the following error for another api.

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Your question helped me to solve my problem.